# Dynamic list for country and city in GUI

Tags: java, sql, swing, jcombobox

I want to create two drop down list for country and city. So if the user selects a country from drop-down list the other drop down list should automatically be refreshed to show its corresponding cities.

```
 public void fillCombo(){
        String sql = " select * from sallytimes.table_name " ;
        try {   
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()){
               jComboBox_Country.addItem(rs.getString("_id"));
               jComboBox_City.addItem(rs.getString("city"));      
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Location.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

How do I progress this?

Comment: I find it interesting how your opening statement is exactly the same as the first post in this forum, from 2010: https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/26492-dynamic-list-country-city.html

Comment: hahahaha...really?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ActionListener to the first combo box to perform an Action when an Item is selected. In the ActionListener you want to replace the model of the second combo box with the new data.

Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JComboBox<String> mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox<String> subComboBox;
    private Hashtable<String, String[]> subItems = new Hashtable<String, String[]>();

    public ComboBoxTwo()
    {
        String[] items = { "Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit" };
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox<String>( items );
        mainComboBox.addActionListener( this );

        //  prevent action events from being fired when the up/down arrow keys are used
        mainComboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
        add( mainComboBox );

        //  Create sub combo box with multiple models

        subComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
        add( subComboBox );

        JButton arrow = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JButton.class, subComboBox, "Text", "");
        Dimension d = arrow.getPreferredSize();
        System.out.println(arrow.getClass());
        System.out.println(d);
        d.width = 35;
        arrow.setPreferredSize(d);

        String[] subItems1 = { "Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);

        String[] subItems2 = { "Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);

        String[] subItems3 = { "Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String item = (String)mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = subItems.get( item );

        if (o == null)
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel() );
        }
        else
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( (String[])o ) );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        try
        {
//          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ComboBoxTwo() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So you would need to modify the code in the ActionListener to get the cities from the database based on the selected country.

Comment: actually i connect the country and city combo-box with MY_SQL database.
now, how i can fix this problem?

Comment: @muhammadsalman, `how i can fix this problem?` - what problem??? YOu have been given working code that shows how to update the second combo box when the item in the first combo box is changed. So all you need to do is get a list of cities from your database. Only you know the structure of your database, so I can't help you with the SQL.